# #include <winsqlite/winsqlite3.h> works in one project, not another

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include-path

From Visual Studio 2017 I created a console application to test Sqlite. The first line I put in my main file was

```
#include <winsqlite/winsqlite3.h>
```

This caused no problem (the location was found). But I tried adding this include to a source file I had obtained by migrating a legacy project to VC++ 2017. This time the include line causes an error.
I suspect I should look at

```
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
```

however, I do not know how I can find out what's in the macros VC_IncludePath and WindowsSDK_IncludePath, let alone change them.

Could there be any other explanation?

Answer (score 1):

**>>however, I do not know how I can find out what's in the macros VC_IncludePath and WindowsSDK_IncludePath, let alone change them.**

In Visual Studio, open Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories->edit->Macros, Then you can check the content of these Macros.

If you need to use a three-party library in Visual Studio, you generally need to add three places in the property page. I will show in the picture below.
[image]
[image]

include is the path of .h file and library is the path of .lib file, and you should also fill the name of .lib file in the third edit box(additional dependencies). In your case, this third-party library seems has only .h file, so just add  the path of .h file to the first edit box. Or simply put the file directly in your project's root directory and add it to your project in Visual Studio, then include it.